# sqlite database creation on building project on Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, sqlite

I'm doing an app who loads data (from a sqlite file) into a sqlite db after the client install it on his iphone.

In Xcode, I select my target,
Then I go in Build Phases -> Add build phase -> Add run script

Then here is my script :

```
echo "Begin script ${TARGET_NAME}"
cd /Users/toto/Documents
cd SQliteDB
sqlite3> db.sql
sqlite3> .read dbfile.sqlite
sqlite3> .exit
echo "end script"
```

The file db.sql is created but : 
When I go to my directory and open the file db.sql with SQlite Database browser it says it's blank... and it's 0ko.

So what's wrong ? When I try this script on the terminal it works perfectly...
The dbfile.sqlite is on the same directory.
When I go to the Build logs after running the App, there is no errors...

Answer (score 0):

`>` is for output redirection; your scripts creates not only a file `db.sql` but also two files `.read` and `.exit`.

The call should look like this:

```
sqlite3 db.sql < dbfile.sqlite
```